# SendError statusmessage/message not existing or displayed wrong

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I make an API call in my nuxt project, which is supposed to fail and throw an error.
I have my contact.post.js in my server/api folder.

I try to send an error in my catch statement
I have

```
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        sendError(event, createError({ statusCode: 400, statusMessage: error}));
    }
```

When i make the API call with an body that throws the error, the `console.log(error)` logs correctly the following: `[ { field: 'email', error: 'Field is required' } ]`
but the status message that gets returned is

```
{
  "url": "/api/contact",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "statusMessage": "",
  "message": "statusMessage.replace is not a function",
  "stack": "<pre><span class=\"stack internal\">at sanitizeStatusMessage (/C:/Users/User/Desktop/Nuxt/nuxt-test/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:474:24)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at createError (/C:/Users/user/Desktop/Nuxt/nuxt-test/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:162:30)</span>\n<span class=\"stack\">at /C:/Users/user/Desktop/Nuxt/nuxt-test/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:814:22</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at async Object.handler (/C:/Users/user/Desktop/Nuxt/nuxt-test/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1285:19)</span>\n<span class=\"stack internal\">at async Server.toNodeHandle (/C:/Users/user/Desktop/Nuxt/nuxt-test/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1360:7)</span></pre>"
}
```

The console also logs  that statusMessage will soon not be used anymore and I should use message instead but if I try it with just message like:

```
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        sendError(event, createError({ statusCode: 400, message: error}));
    }
```

it still logs the same correct information in the console but it returns

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "stack": []
}
```

without the message at all.

What am I doing wrong here?

I provided the problematic parts of the code above but here is the rest, in case the error is somewhere else here:

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'
import validator from 'validator'

const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: config.MAILHOST,
    port: config.MAILPORT,

})

export default defineEventHandler (async(event) => {
    try{
        const body = await readBody(event);

        await isValid(body)
        
        const mail = transporter.sendMail({
            form: 'test',
            to: 'here is an email which I switched with this',
            subject: body.subject,
            text: body.message,
            html: body.message,
        })
        return 'Gesendet!'
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        sendError(event, createError({ statusCode: 400, message: error}));
    }
})

async function isValid(body) {
    const errors = []

    if (validator.isEmpty(body.email || '')) 
    errors.push({
        field: 'email',
        error: 'Field is required'
    })
    

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        console.log(errors)
        return Promise.reject(errors);
    }
    else {
        return Promise.resolve({})
    }
}
```

I make the api request via thunder client plugin from vscode
its a post request with the following body:

```
{
  "email":"",
  "name": "A",
  "subject": "sub",
  "message": "Hello Word"
}
```